# Migrating Gecko 1.9 to 2.0 - Lot of errors

Tags: gecko

OK, after migrated to Gecko 2.0 for my XPCOM Component, 
I fixed a couple of thg like below:
1. Replacing #include "nsIGenericFactory.h" to #include "mozilla/ModuleUtils.h"
2. Replacing xpcomglue_s.lib to xpcomglue_s_nomozalloc.lib
3. Adding #include "mozilla-config.h" to xpcom-config.h header file
4. And as well as remove a couple of unused header file eg: nsReadableUtils.h, nsEventQueueUtils.h, nsIExtensionManager.h
5. Replacing NS_DEFINE_STATIC_IID_ACCESSOR(IMYPROGRAM_IID) to NS_DEFINE_STATIC_IID_ACCESSOR(IMyProgram, IMYPROGRAM_IID)

Reduced from 200+ errors to 20+ now, below are a few more errors which i have no idea what is that, any expert here encounter problem like below?

```
error C3254: 'IMyProgram' : class contains explicit override 'kIID' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration
error C2838: 'kIID' : illegal qualified name in member declaration
error C3857: 'IMyProgram::kIID': multiple template parameter lists are not allowed
error C2084: function 'void nsTraceRefcnt::LogAddRef(void *,nsrefcnt,const char *,PRUint32)' already has a body
error C2084: function 'void nsTraceRefcnt::LogRelease(void *,nsrefcnt,const char *)' already has a body
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'components'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'const char [13]' to 'int'
error C2078: too many initializers
error C2448: 'NS_IMPL_NSGETMODULE' : function-style initializer appears to be a function definition
error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '__stdcall'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2556: 'int MyProgramRegistration(nsIComponentManager *,nsIFile *,const char *,const char *,const int)' : overloaded function differs only by return type from 'nsresult MyProgramRegistration(nsIComponentManager *,nsIFile *,const char *,const char *,const int)'
error C2371: 'MyProgramRegistration' : redefinition; different basic types
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
error C2143: syntax error : missing ',' before '*'
error C3254: 'IMyProgram' : class contains explicit override 'kIID' but does not derive from an interface that contains the function declaration
error C2838: 'kIID' : illegal qualified name in member declaration
error C3857: 'IMyProgram::kIID': multiple template parameter lists are not allowed
```

Comment: If you are using VS 2010 try adding these pre-processor definitions XPCOM_GLUE_USE_NSPR; XPCOM_GLUE_S and link against xpcomglue_s.lib; xpcom.lib;nspr4.lib these libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very least it looks as if you are missing an `NS_DECLARE_STATIC_IID_ACCESSOR(IMYPROGRAM_IID)` in your interface (xpidl would have generated that for you automatically.) Some of the other errors are a bit harder to figure out without source code, but the chances are that you haven't quite managed to update your module registration code correctly.